# cumulative application of a function over a dimension in R

Tags: r, performance, multidimensional-array

I would like to speed up what is shown in the pseudo code below to the fastest possible one in R (vectorized, or any method that is faster than a simple for loop).

Imaging I have a 4-dimensional array `A` (filled arbitrarily with 1 just as an example):

`A = array(runif(nx*ny*nz*nt), c(nx,ny,nz,nt))`

and I want to do this for loop faster (fill up the `output` array which has a higher 2nd dimension in a cumulative fashion from its previous value ... more like a cumulative product of the second dimension of the input `A` array:

```
output = array(1, c(nx, ny+1, nz, nt))
for (x in 1:nx)
{
  for (z in 1:nz)
  {
    for (t in 1:nt)
    {
      for (y in 2:(ny+1))
      {
        output[x,y,z,t] = output[x,y-1,z,t] * (1 - A[x,y-1,z,t])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do this faster? using `apply()`? or some smart cumulative product with `abind()` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use `apply` and `cumprod` to get the same result (`aperm` is necessary because the results of the function called by apply end up in the first dimension):

```
output1 <- aperm(apply(A,c(1,3,4),function(v) cumprod(1-v)),c(2,1,3,4))
```

Comparing the result to `output` the differences are all very close to `.Machine$double.eps`:

```
> max(abs(output[,2:11,,]-output1))
[1] 1.110223e-16
> .Machine$double.eps
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

Note that `output1` does not contain `output[,1,,]`, but this matrix is just filled with ones:

```
> all(output[,1,,]==1)
[1] TRUE
```

Thus `output1` could be easily extended if that is desired.

For `nx = ny = nz = nt = 10` this method is clearly better:

```
nx = ny = nz = nt = 10
A = array(runif(nx*ny*nz*nt), c(nx,ny,nz,nt))

f.old <- function(){
  output = array(1, c(nx, ny+1, nz, nt))
  for (x in 1:nx)
  {
    for (z in 1:nz)
    {
      for (t in 1:nt)
      {
        for (y in 2:(ny+1))
        {
          output[x,y,z,t] = output[x,y-1,z,t] * (1 - A[x,y-1,z,t])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

f.new <- function() aperm(apply(A,c(1,3,4),function(v) cumprod(1-v)),c(2,1,3,4))
```

Then `microbenchmark` yields (on my machine):

```
> microbenchmark(f.old(),f.new())
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 f.old() 49.553825 53.486576 61.701149 57.710147 62.862921 136.02883   100
 f.new()  2.036781  2.365426  2.988266  2.685126  3.396083  10.88668   100
```

Comment: Jonathan, you are amazing! This is indeed much much faster. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. The functions from the `apply`-family and vectorization are usually your friends when you are concerned about the speed of your code.